# Dynamically-generated Button not clicking React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a button in my `react` component and it's `onClick` callback is never triggering. The component is generated based on data in a `.map` function and it looks and behaves correctly other than the button. I have two buttons (flagged in code), neither of which work. Here is the code:

```
var namesList = this.state.data.map(function(name, index){
                return (
                  <div>
                        <a class="btn" onCLick={() => alert('alert')} style={{width: '70%', marginTop: '33px'}}>
                          <span>click</span>
                        </a>
                        <button onCLick={() => alert('alert')} > button </button>
                  </div>
                );
              })
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a typo here:

```
onCLick={() => alert(‘alert’)}
```

Should be:

```
onClick={() => alert('alert')}
```

Comment: Just updated it, the only adjustment was the one you outlined

Comment: did you try with lowercase "l" ? onClick

Comment: Code updated again to isolate the issue, check it out.

Comment: The "L" is still written uppercased. Try what I wrote above.